# Best way to add background image in RWD theme

Tags: html, css, magento, magento-1.9, responsive

Simply put, what's the best way to simply add a store-wide background image in the RDW theme ?

I'm using the default RwD theme in Magento 1.9.2, and I can't seem to figure out how to just add an image, not insert it in CMS, not a block, just a static background image on the whole page instead of the default white colour.

I've been trying to add it, like you usually would, in styles.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center; 
    font-family:futura;
    background-image:url(../images/Fond-Portail.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    background-position: center top; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The URL should be correct, this is usually a very simple task but I think RWD makes it harder. The only solutions I've seen to this problem, while searching, were to use a community module, is it really that complicated or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this question! Here's how I fixed it :

First of all don't forget (like I did) to remove lines like background: #FFFFFF;, otherwise the color will be overlayed on top of your image.

Turns out you have to change this at multiple lines for RWD's styles.css,

I added the background image in BASE body{},

removed the colored background in RESET body{},

and changed the background color and size of GLOBAL .wrapper{} (depending on the way it's configured for you, I changed the width and made it partially transparent).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background size property like this.  `background-size:cover;` and you can also try background-size:contain; if it works for you.